# Вычислить расстояние через геокоординаты

Tags: c++

Даны координаты 2-х городов на Земле. Нужно вычислить расстояние между ними. Как это можно сделать?

Радиус Земли: `R = 6 371 302` м. Ответ необходимо получить в километрах.

Допустим: даются 4 значения (координаты обоих точек: широта1, долгота1, широта2, долгота2) `55 37.620393 43.116418 131.882475`.
После чего, с помощью каких то преобразований, должно выйти число 6458.
Вот код, который выдает неверное значение (выходит - 8836):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265  
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int res = 0, R = 6371302;
    double alet, along, blet, blong;
    cin >> alet >> along >> blet >> blong;
    alet = alet*(180/PI);
    blet = blet*(180/PI);
    along = along*(180/PI);
    blong = blong*(180/PI);
    res = R* acos(sin(alet)*sin(blet)+cos(alet)*cos(blet)*cos(along-blong))/1000;
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дуга большого круга - по этому термину легко найти. Впрочем, вы уже нашли формулу. Можно поискать на английском: Great-circle distance. Готовый код так же банально ищется.

Comment: Хочу всех огорчить.. Формула вычисляет не правильное значение.. за место 6458 он мне выдает 4к (55 37.620393 43.116418 131.882475)
Коорддинаты.. Нашел еще формулу, но ее реализовать куда сложнее..http://gis-lab.info/qa/great-circles.html

Comment: По поводу вашего кода, вы углы вводите в градусах, а функция принимает в радианах. А даст ли формула исправленая (град-в-радианы) хорошее значение - не могу сказать.

Comment: Спасибо.. Но проблема не решилась, теперь выдает 8836..

Comment: Попробуйте формулу из ответа.

Comment: асоциация http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198985/calculating-the-distance-between-2-latitudes-and-longitudes-that-are-saved-in-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расстояние через геокоординаты (две пары чисел широта и долгота) в километрах, можно вычислить так:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath> 
#define earthRadiusKm 6371.0

// This function converts decimal degrees to radians
double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * M_PI / 180);
}

//  This function converts radians to decimal degrees
double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180 / M_PI);
}

/**
 * Returns the distance between two points on the Earth.
 * Direct translation from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
 * @param lat1d Latitude of the first point in degrees
 * @param lon1d Longitude of the first point in degrees
 * @param lat2d Latitude of the second point in degrees
 * @param lon2d Longitude of the second point in degrees
 * @return The distance between the two points in kilometers
 */
double distanceEarth(double lat1d, double lon1d, double lat2d, double lon2d) {
  double lat1r, lon1r, lat2r, lon2r, u, v;
  lat1r = deg2rad(lat1d);
  lon1r = deg2rad(lon1d);
  lat2r = deg2rad(lat2d);
  lon2r = deg2rad(lon2d);
  u = sin((lat2r - lat1r)/2);
  v = sin((lon2r - lon1r)/2);
  return 2.0 * earthRadiusKm * asin(sqrt(u * u + cos(lat1r) * cos(lat2r) * v * v));
}
```

Ссылки:

- Источник [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198985/calculating-the-distance-between-2-latitudes-and-longitudes-that-are-saved-in-a)
- Формулы http://mapgroup.com.ua/glavnaya/astronomicheskie-kalkulyatory/1009-rasstoyanie-mezhdu-dvumya-koordinatamirasstoyanie-mezhdu-dvumya-koordinatami
- Вики http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle_distance
- Калькулятор http://www.garmin.com.ua/tools/calc.php

Answer (score 1):

Найдите угол между векторами из центра к этим точкам (переведите полярные координаты в декартовы) и умножьте на радиус.

> ответ в кМ

разделите в конце на тысячу )

Comment: С этим то и проблема......
Вот такую формулу нашел.. А как ее реализовать..
d = arccos {sin(Фa)·sin(Фb) + cos(Фa)·cos(Фb)·cos(Лa - Лb)},

Comment: @tebenkov2222 э-э-э, не-е-ет. По готовой формуле код за Вас писать - увольте.

Comment: ахаха, извиняюсь.. Я формулу найти не мог.. Думал, что может быть у кого то есть готовый вариант кода.. Вот и обратился сюда)